# Route URL in Google Maps Distance Service API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I'm making a call to get multiple routes from google maps Distance Service API and I'm able to get a successful response. But I want to get the route URL (shortURL), so if the client clicks on the link he'll be directly redirected to google maps showing the route. Here is my code:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    return directionsService.route({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    }, shortestRoute);
```

Comment: The Directions API does not automatically produce a maps.google.com link. You'll have to produce the link yourself easily by using [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=START&destination=FINISH&travelmode=driving

Answer (score 2):

If you are not trying to use the Google Maps Directions Service for navigation purposes, what you could do instead is dynamically supply the (shortURL) based on user input assuming you are listening to user input on your side of the application.

One simple implementation is that you provide the [(shortURL)](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1) right off the bat so that users may type the Directions information on the actual [Google Maps page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#modes) instead of on your site assuming you are not loading a modal and/or iframe since you mentioned redirecting.

Now if you are not planning on redirecting before the user inputs their data. You could setup something like:

See [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#modes).

```
var origin;

// This function gets called when you are ready to submit the user's input. 
function directionsOrigin(){ 
  var origin = document.getElementById('origin-input').value;
  placeholdDynamicInput(origin);
}

function placeholdDynamicInput(origin, dynamicUrl){
  // Following this
  // protocol-> https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters

  var url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=' + origin;

  // Dynamically create your placeholder URL using user input.
}

function dynamicUrl(){
  // Handle this function however makes sense with your application
}
```